# Can't use integer as an array index

Tags: java, android, loops, asynchronous, integer

I am trying to pass an integer to a Async task and access a list by that index withing.

However I get this error "in List cannot be applied".

Here is the relevant code.

The Async task doesn't accept primitive int as an argument.

```
src = new ArrayList<String>();
String message = "";
for (int i=0; i<src.size(); i++) {
    new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... pos) {
        ...
        message += **src.get(pos)**;
        ...    
        }
    }.execute(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a varargs, translatable into an `Integer[]` as argument for your `ArrayList#get` invocation, which will not compile - see `List` [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-).

You need to pick the desired element of your varargs, e.g. `pos[0]`, which will be unboxed to an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a varargs parameter which is basically an `Array`. You have to access it with the index e.g.

```
message += src.get(pos[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter that you are passing to get the element from the collection is basically an array. So if you are sending multiple int values while executing the AsyncTask,  you need to use the index of the value that you have passed. In your case the code should access the index in this way:

```
message += src.get(pos[0]);
```